nextjs google sign in
I'm just curious about sign-in/authentication libraries like for example is clerk and Lucia.
right now I'm using nextAuth with a simple sign in to google, the process is opening console.cloud.google, and doing a few setups to get the GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID & GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET for getting permissions and once access is granted i would be able to modify,create folders,upload files & delete files/folders on my google drive
.
So my curiosities is, can i use other authentication libraries like clerk and lucia, to get a equivalent of GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET & GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID= in which can grant me access to my google account?
Hope my question makes sense to y'all

The auth library has little to do with it. As long as you have a token which identifies you and the app created in the console has the correct rights to access the drive, you can do this with any auth libraries.
